# User-Exit EXIT_SAPMM07M_003 is not triggered

Tags: include, hook, abap, sap-erp

When I created batches manually or from goods movement, the program seems to be NOT passing through the codes I created in the user exit include. When I create batch and save it, it does not stop in the breakpoint inside the user exit include..., that is why I concluded that the exit was not even been triggered.

When I debug the codes I created in the user-exit separately, all the values are in place, and data retrieval goes fine, so it is a mystery why the value is not reflected in the table MCHA?

Do I need to configure or activate something???

Answer (score 2):

You can activate or de-activate a User-Exit in transaction CMOD.